# Using Pycharm debugger with Airflow running locally

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, airflow

I am using Airflow locally to execute some ETL tasks (everything is done locally using Airflow, Python and Docker), I have a task which failed.

If I could get to use Pycharm debugger it would be great. I am looking for a way so that Pycharm listen to what is happening on Airflow (localhost/airflow) so that once I run a task on Airflow I only need to jump to Pycharm to start debugging and see the logs.

I have read about remote debbug server but what I see on tutorials is that they all run their programm using Pycharm with a main function inside the file.

What I want is to launch my task through Airflow and then jump to Pycharm to see the logs and start debugging.

So I started something but I am not sure if this is the good way, when I try to add a remote interpreter to my project (preference/interpreter/add/docker compose here is what I get.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSHPC.png)